# Stackrel redefine font problem

Tags: stack

I am using `stackrelsp` redefined command for `\leftharpoonup` symbol height adjusting. But the subscript font size is not working for me.

The default stackrel command follow the mathsizes (10, 7, 5). I will try to retain the default stackrel font settings for my defined command `stackrelsp`
But the same text font size is follow the command. How to get this default font settings.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\def\stackrelsp#1#2{%
  \mathrel{\vbox{\offinterlineskip\ialign{%
    \hfil##\hfil\cr
    $#1$\cr
    \noalign{\kern-0.2pt}
    $#2${}\cr
}}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\eta _{(\stackrel{\leftharpoonup}{m},\stackrel{\rightharpoonup}{m})_{(\stackrel{\leftharpoonup}{A}_{i}^{l} ,\stackrel{\rightharpoonup}{A}_{i}^{l} )} }
\end{equation}



\begin{equation}
\eta _{(\stackrelsp{\leftharpoonup}{m},\stackrelsp{\rightharpoonup}{m})_{(\stackrelsp{\leftharpoonup}{A}_{i}^{l} ,\stackrelsp{\rightharpoonup}{A}_{i}^{l} )} }
\end{equation}



\end{document}
```

My Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`scalerel` to the rescue.  Here, the `\ThisStyle{...\SavedStyle...}` syntax allows the current math style (`obtained at \ThisStyle`) to be imported to areas where it would otherwise be lost (reconstituted at `\SavedStyle`).  It is a compact way to express more verbose `\mathchoice`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{scalerel}

\def\stackrelsp#1#2{\ThisStyle{%
  \mathrel{\vbox{\offinterlineskip\ialign{%
    \hfil##\hfil\cr
    $\SavedStyle#1$\cr
    \noalign{\kern-0.2pt}
    $\SavedStyle#2${}\cr
}}}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\eta _{(\stackrel{\leftharpoonup}{m},\stackrel{\rightharpoonup}{m})_{(\stackrel{\leftharpoonup}{A}_{i}^{l} ,\stackrel{\rightharpoonup}{A}_{i}^{l} )} }
\end{equation}



\begin{equation}
\eta _{(\stackrelsp{\leftharpoonup}{m},\stackrelsp{\rightharpoonup}{m})_{(\stackrelsp{\leftharpoonup}{A}_{i}^{l} ,\stackrelsp{\rightharpoonup}{A}_{i}^{l} )} }
\end{equation}



\end{document}
```

[image]

Thus, it will continue to work even if the default math sizes are changed, for example, in the preamble with

```
\makeatletter
\DeclareMathSizes{\@xpt}{\@xpt}{3}{3}
\makeatother
```

[image]

Comment: your solution working excellent.

Answer (score 1):

You need `\mathpalette`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\rhu}[1]{\vetriaccent{\rightharpoonup}{#1}}
\newcommand{\lhu}[1]{\vetriaccent{\leftharpoonup}{#1}}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\vetriaccent}[2]{{%
  \mathpalette\vetri@accent@i{{#1}{#2}}%
}}
\newcommand{\vetri@accent@i}[2]{\vetri@accent@ii#1#2}
\newcommand{\vetri@accent@ii}[3]{%
  \vbox{\offinterlineskip
    \ialign{%
      \hfil##\hfil\cr
      $\m@th#1#2$\cr
      $\m@th#1#3$\cr
    }%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[
(\lhu{m},\rhu{m})_{(\lhu{m},\rhu{m})_{(\lhu{A_{i}^{l}},\rhu{A_{i}^{l}})}}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your solution accents control is very useful for me. Your solution is working excellent. Thanks for your support